# ETSY Api PHP Obtaining Token Credentials

Tags: php, api, access-token, etsy

I'm using y0lk package to help me with OAuth1 and ETSY App, I managed to get the temporary credentials, but can't get my hand on Access tokens.

here's what I do :

```
$client = new Etsy([
    'identifier'    => '*********************',
    'secret'        => '*********',
    'scope'         => 'listings_r transactions_r',
    'callback_uri'  => 'http://*********.loc/slider/'
]);

$tempCred = $client->getTemporaryCredentials();
    
$tmpSecret = $tempCred->getSecret();
$tmpId = $tempCred->getIdentifier();

// Redirect to Etsy Autorisation login page
$redirect_url = $client->getAuthorizationUrl($tempCred);

$accessTokens = $client->getTokenCredentials($tempCred, $tmpId, $_GET['oauth_verifier']);
```

Ok, I don't know how to do, because to obtain the oauth verifier ( and do the `$_GET['oauth_verifier']`), I have to go by the login page, and then, to get the access token, I need my temp credentials, but to get then I 'll have to go again by `new Etsy`  and this is why I always got the token revoked error..

I'm beginner, in PHP and with API, if someone see other mistakes in my way to do this, feel free to point them out for me :)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: also I have this error that I don't know what to do with :

` Warning: Declaration of Y0lk\OAuth1\Client\Server\Etsy::getAuthorizationUrl($temporaryIdentifier) should be compatible with League\OAuth1\Client\Server\Server::getAuthorizationUrl($temporaryIdentifier, array $options = Array `